# Pause between call onNext in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

How to make delay between onNext method calling? I have a code:

```
Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.range(1, 1000)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            subs = obs.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer number) {
                    mCurrentNumber = number;
                    mCounter.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    isRunning = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });
```

For example, I need to set a pause for 100 milliseconds

Comment: Do you want the `setText` numbers to be something like: `1,2,3...1000` or `1,100,200...1000` or randomly around 100 like `1,97,102,203....` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use [interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) operator which will emit items after a specified interval of time and use take operator to use only required numbers of stream items

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .take(1000)
         .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
          @Override public void call(Long timerValue) {

        }
        });
```

Comment: So with RxJava2 they removed the  action1 class
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#functional-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use zip to combine your observable with an Interval observable to delay the output.

```
 Observable.zip(Observable.range(1, 5)
    .groupBy(n -> n % 5)
    .flatMap(g -> g.toList()),
Observable.interval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
(obs, timer) -> obs)
.doOnNext(item -> {
  System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeNow);
  System.out.println(item);
  System.out.println(" ");
}).toList().toBlocking().first();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `1,2,3...1000` how about this:

```
subs = Observable.interval(0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .take(1000)
        .map(counter -> counter++)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Long number) {
                mCurrentNumber = number;
                mCounter.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                isRunning = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }
        });
```

- .interval will run on IO
- This will start immediately emitting items `0L, 1L, 2L......infinity`.
- The `.take(1000)` will take the first 1000 items and then stop (complete)
- The `.map(counter -> counter++)` will transform the above to `1L, 2L,......infinity` because you requested from 1 to 1000 in your example and not 0 to 1000.

If you want 100,200,300 then use `.map(counter -> counter*100)`

If you want to "sample" per 100ms the range, thus creating a bit random numbers then use:

```
Observable.range(1, 1000)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .sample(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        ......
        //rest here
```

Comment: only one correction: the .interval operator operates by default on the computation Scheduler and not on the IO one.

Comment: @nicopasso that's correct. In my example however it will run on IO :)

Comment: oh yes sorry I've completely missed it :)