# How do I convert this RxJava observable to emit results every 200 ms?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have this Observable:

```
Observable<String> concatenatedSets =
            Observable.just("1/5/8", "1/9/11/58/16/", "9/15/56/49/21");

    concatenatedSets.flatMap(s -> Observable.from(s.split("/")))
            .map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(i -> tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
```

how do I convert it or what operator do I chain up to it so that `onNext` is called with 200 ms in between calls?

I was looking at this SO question:
[Pause between call onNext in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583416/pause-between-call-onnext-in-rxjava)

but answers there start with creating a pause using `interval` like so

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

However, I am creating my observable in another way (using `just`), so how do I mix both functionalities (`just` and `interval`) or what do I do to achieve a pause of 200 ms between emissions?

PS: just tried `delay` - it postponed overall execution once by the time I provided. `zip` might be the answer but it is very confusing, so how do I zip my observable and an interval one?

Comment: did you try delay operator? or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291245/rxjava-delay-for-each-item-of-list-emitted

Comment: just tried `delay` - it postponed overall execution once by the time I provided. `zip` might be the answer but it is very confusing, so how do I zip my observable and an interval one?

Comment: Take a look at custom operator first. Forgot to notice it :) https://gist.github.com/matir91/aac2c1318a1a1facd811

Comment: Thank you, I will use this custom operator as a last resort if I can't find a way to use `zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just("1/5/8", "1/9/11/58/16/", "9/15/56/49/21")
                .flatMap(s -> Observable.from(s.split("/")))
                .map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s));

Observable<Integer> zippedObservable = Observable.zip(
                observable,
                Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                (number, interval) -> number);

zippedObservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(i -> tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the function argument in `.zip` do?

Comment: The function takes two item from both Observables, and returns one item that will be emmited by zip Observable.
Here is document: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(rx.Observable,%20rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2)